# Express 4: router syntax

Tags: node.js, rest, express, express-4

I am using Express 4 with the new router. At least one thing continues to confuse me, and it is a syntax problem - I am wondering if there is a regex that can do what I want. I have a standard REST api, but I want to add batch updates, so that I can send all the info to update some users models with one request, instead of one PUT request per user, for example. Anyway, I currently route all requests to the users resources, like so:

```
app.use('/users, userRoutes);
```

in userRoutes.js:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

   //gets all users
});


router.put('/:user_id', function (req, res, next) {

   //updates a single user
});
```

but now I want a route that captures a batch request, something like this:

```
router.put('/Batch', function (req, res, next) {


     //this picks up an array of users from the JSON in req.body and updates all

});
```

in other words, I want something which translates to:

```
app.use('/usersBatch, function(req,res,next){

  }
```

...but with the new router. I can't get the syntax right.

I tried this:

```
app.use('/users*, userRoutes);
```

but that doesn't work. Does anyone know how to design this?

Answer (score 0):

REST doesn't include a POST as a list syntax.  That's because each URL in REST point to an individual resource.

As an internet engineer I haven't seen any bulk PUTs or POSTs, but that said, it's *your* app, so you can make whatever API you like.  There are definitely use cases for it.

You'll still need to describe it to Express.  I would do it like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/',            function (req, res) {}); // gets all users
router.post('/:user_id',   function (req, res) {}); // one user
router.put('/:user_id',    function (req, res) {}); // one user
router.patch('/:user_id',  function (req, res) {}); // one user
router.delete('/:user_id', function (req, res) {}); // one user

app.use('/user', router);  // Notice the /user/:user_id is *singular*

var pluralRouter = express.Router();
pluralRouter.post('/', function (req, res) {
   // req.body is an array.  Process this array with a foreach
   // using more or less the same code you used in router.post()
});
pluralRouter.put('/', function (req, res) {
   // req.body is another array.  Have items in the array include
   // their unique ID's.  Process this array with a foreach
   // using +/- the same code in router.put()
});

app.use('/users', pluralRouter);  // Notice the PUT /users/ is *plural*
```

There are other ways to do this.  Including putting comma-delimited parameters in the URL.  E.g.

```
GET /user/1,2,3,4
```

But this isn't that awesome to use, and vague in a PUT or POST. Parallel arrays are evil.

All in all, it's a niche use case, so do what works best.  Remember, the server is built to serve the client.  Figure out what the client needs and serve.

Comment: one reason I want to do the batch is because I don't like seeing all the requests in either my server and browser development console! So basically what you are saying is I need an entirely new router instance to do /usersBatch, instead of lumping that route with the other routes for /users. Seems unfortunate. There must be some regex I can put in app.use('/users....', routeHandler) that can do this!

Comment: the way I was thinking of doing batch, by the way, is this JSON on the client ---> var batch = {create:[],update:[],destroy:[]}. Then in one request to the server I can specify which models to update, which to create, which to delete, etc. Obviously, for a server getting a lot of requests from different places, this will tie up the server a bit longer than smaller more numerous requests, but I think it might be worth a shot. Surprised you haven't seen it much.

Comment: Hey Olegzandr, `router`'s are free, so don't worry about it :-)  It's common to have a router for each piece of an API.  If you don't like logging in the console, you can turn it off - try deleting the logger.  Maybe 'morgan'?  Lastly, no - long requests tie up the server more than short requests.  It's much easier to scale small simple things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the call to `[PUT] /users/Batch` is being picked up by the `[PUT] /users/:user_id` route. The string `/:user_id` is used as a regular expression causing it to also collect `/Batch`.

You can either move `/Batch` before `/:user_id` in the route order, refine the regex of `/:user_id` to not catch `/Batch` or change `/Batch` to something that won't get picked up too early.

(plus all the stuff Michael said)

Comment: thanks Joe, actually I am certain that this is not the case. The actual URL I request from the client is /usersBatch (no second slash). The new Express 4 router is werid in that it requires you to strip 'xxx' from your router.routes. hard to explain so I won't bother unfortunately.

Comment: this article demonstrates what I am trying to say: http://matthewgladney.com/blog/angular/using-regex-with-node-express-router/ ...basically, it is app.use('/api', myRouter); then myRouter.get('/users') actually is pointing to an originalURL of '/api/users'.

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were going for the split route (second slash). Hope you get it figured out.

Comment: I don't think I did yet (can't remember) but when I figured it out will post back on this thread